# Can't spawn process in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm not quite sure why I can't get this but I'm sure the answer is extraordinarily simple. I'm just testing out a few things and in my tests discovered that I would like to spawn a process within `handle_info` of my `gen_server`.

However despite me trying different combinations the best result I'm getting from my child is dying with an error and returning `{undef, [{bob, hello, [], []}]}`.

Code:

```
-module(test).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-export([start_link/1, init/1, handle_call/3, handle_cast/2, handle_info/2, terminate/2, code_change/3]).

start_link(Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, Args}, ?MODULE, Args, []).

init(Args) ->
    io:format("Init ~p ~p~n",[self(), Args]),
    {ok, Args}.

handle_call(_, _, State) ->
    io:format("Call ~p~n",[self()]),
    {reply, ok, State}.

handle_cast(_, State) ->
    io:format("Cast ~p~n",[self()]),
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info(_, State) ->
    io:format("Info ~p~n",[self()]),
    spawn(?MODULE,fun hello/1,[]),
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_, _) ->
    ok.

code_change(_, State, _) ->
    {ok, State}.

hello([]) ->
    io:format("WOOT ~p~n",[self()]).
```

My first goal was to determine if multiple servers could be started with one module. The second was if `handle_info` was executed in a separate process... for some reason when I read it was asynchronous I thought it was in another process. Now the third is to spawn a process within that call.

My typical shell goes something like (with comments):

```
> c(test), {ok, P} = gen_server:start_link(bob)
> %% Warns me the function hello in any incarnation is not used
> P ! woot.
> %% An error of some kind depending on what I've done
> f(P), gen_server:stop(bob).
```

I've used `hello/1` with `[]` and `_`, `hello/0`. As well as `spawn/1`, `spawn/3`, `spawn_link/1` and `spawn_link/3`... I've used `?MODULE`, `test`, `State` and for chuckles `{local, State}` as the module parameter. I've parted with what I've seen on multiple websites and put in `fun hello/0` and `fun hello/1` when passing the function. This produces crashes but got rid of the compiler warning.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument to [spawn/3](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=2&search=spawn#spawn/3) is a list containing the number of arguments which the spawned function requires.  For instance, if the spawned function takes 1 argument, the list will contain 1 argument; and if the spawned function takes 3 arguments, the list will contain 3 arguments.  Finally, if the spawned function takes 0 arguments, the list will contain 0 arguments, i.e. the empty list.

You defined `hello` like this:

```
hello([]) ->
    io:format("WOOT ~p~n",[self()]).
```

That's a function with arity 1, and not only that, the only argument that matches the function is the empty list.  In order to pass one argument to a function that you spawn, you would have to write:

```
spawn(?MODULE, hello ,[SomeArg])
```

And, because you want to match a function that takes the empty list as its only argument, SomeArg has to be the empty list:

```
spawn(?MODULE, hello, [[]])
```

Note that the syntax for `spawn/3` is MFA, or module name, function name, arguments, which is a list containing the arguments.

Next, you have two more problems:

1. You shouldn't call `gen_server:start_link(bob)` as you did here:

   ```
   {ok, P} = gen_server:start_link(bob)
   ```

   There is no such function as `gen_server:start_link/1`.  Instead, you need to call your user interface function `start_link/1`, which then calls `gen_server:start_link/3`.  You might want to rename your user interface function `my_gen_server_starter()`, so that you are clear about what it does.
2. > %% Warns me the function hello in any incarnation is not used

   You have to export a function to be able to spawn it.  Because you didn't export the function and because no functions inside the module call the function, that means the function can never execute.

Comment: In the combinations I tried I just must've typed in #1 by faulty brain recollection. I also did at some point match the arguments correctly to my `spawn` call. That was a detail on multiple pages I saw. The solution was #2. I just copy/pasted and removed all the fluff from an IDE... I usually use `export_all` .... I have no idea how long it would've taken me to determine the solution.